# What am I doing wrong with jQuery event handling and hiding/showing image elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am working on a gallery at http://icon.stornge.com, where the intended functionality is for the user to click on a link on the homepage, then have a first image display, then if/when the user clicks on the image, the next limit loads, and so on until the last image.

What is happening instead is that the first click loads the image, first a sliver and then the full image (is this the intended behavior of `jQuery.load('slow')` on an image?`</a>`), and then clicking on the first image appears to call the event handler (if I put an `alert()` it displays as expected), but the first image stays in its place, and the second image does not appear. Chrome's console does not register any JavaScript errors.

Are there interactions between jQuery's event handling and `.hide()` and `.show()`? Am I getting in trouble by having an initial CSS "`display: none`" or anything else?

What should I change so that clicking on one image loads the next?

Comment: Can you please share your code? You may have something out of place or simply misspelled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, though it works (surprisingly -- but, maybe only in Chrome) the protocol should be all lowercase (javascript:, not JavaScript:). Second, any href using script, which does not return false (after all script code in the href), can cause problems.

Anyway, just use the following:

1- <strike>Apply a class (ex. "image-toggle") to the the images and links which you want to trigger an image to appear.</strike> Add class "icon" to the anchor.

2- Change the current href to # or javascript:return false;

3- Remove the IDs from the images (W3C HTML specs clearly state that ID values must begin with an alpha character; you can use numbers -- but, you cannot start the ID with a number).

4- (optional) Place all images (to rotate) in a new DIV (call it "Images").

Add this code to your page (in a script block):

```
(function($){
  var imageIndex = 0;
  $(function(){
    var $homepage = $("#homepage"), 
        $images = $(".icon");
    $images.click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $homepage.hide("slow");
      $images.hide().eq(imageIndex++).show("slow");
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: One thing I neglected (though it wasn't necessarily clear in the question), is what to do after the last image is shown... but, you can always add a conditional in the click function to reset the index. Ex. if (imageIndex > $images.length) imageIndex = 0; -- if you add this before the $images.hide() [...] line, the last image will then rotate back to the first image.

Answer (score 0):

The flicker you notice is probably because you don't hide the homepage until after you start showing the first image. You can consider trying [`.fadeIn('slow')`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) as an alternative too.

Also, you need to bind the other click handlers after the dom is ready. I would advise moving your script out of the `a` element's href and all into one script tag containing the code below. There is no need to index the elements, since you can use the [jQuery `.next()` method](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to access the next icon.

There are also a few issues with your html that I corrected/modified. [Here is a demo of the effect](http://jsfiddle.net/GDgyq/4/).

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Icon Library</title>
        <style>
            /*...*/
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="homepage">
        <h1>Icon Library</h1>
        <p><del>Favorites</del><br>
        <a href="#" id="icons">Browse icons</a><br>
        <a href="http://JonathansCorner.com/">by CJSH</a><br>
        </p>
        </div>
        <img class="icon" src="icon/icon0.png">
        <img class="icon" src="icon/icon1.png">
        <img class="icon" src="icon/icon2.png">
        <img class="icon" src="icon/icon3.png">
        <script>
            /*...*/
        </script>
</body></html>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#icons").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#homepage').hide();
        $('img.icon:first').show('slow');
    });
    $('img.icon').click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).next('img').show();
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aCpBJ/5/). It shows you a possibly reasonable way to organize your page. I hope it is useful to you.

Here's the code:

```
var currentIcon = -1;
function nextIcon() {
    currentIcon = currentIcon % 3 + 1;
    $('#icons img')
       .attr('src', $('#iconlibrary img:eq(' + currentIcon + ')').attr('src'));
}

$('#leftpanel a').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('disabled')) { return; }
    $(this)
        .blur()
        .parent()
        .addClass('selected')
        .siblings()
        .removeClass('selected');                  
    $('#' + $(this).data('id'))
    .show()
    .siblings()
    .hide();
    return false;
});

$('#icons a').on('click', nextIcon);
nextIcon();
```

Hmmm I just realized you wanted a slow fade in. Let me think about it. It also has a small problem with the images gaining the active selection border when clicked. If you are concerned about usability, then I would leave the links in and make them submit to the server, which displays a new page with the correct image showing. Then, in javascript, on page load get rid of the link and instead use plain `img` tags with a click handler and CSS pointer styling to make the hand show.

Let me know if you like the direction I was taking this in and I'll try to help you more.

P.S. Hi Jonathan. Good to see you again. Some day I'll get you a response to our (very old, very stale) conversation.